# Why liferay taglib <liferay-util:include > is not working?

Tags: liferay

The taglib liferay-util:include is used in the liferay user_admin`s jsp pages.

I use it in my portlet view.jsp like :

```
<liferay-util:include page="/html/book.jsp"   servletContext="<%=this.getServletContext() %>" />
```

and i include the taglib like :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
```

There is not any errors when i go to view.jsp. but the page book.jsp is not included in the view.jsp.

what is wrong?

Comment: somebody help me please.

Comment: What does `this.getServletContext()` resolve?

Comment: Can you either try with `request.getServletContext()` or `request.getSession().getServletContext()`?

Comment: @Parkash Kumar thakx. i try with your options  but id doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me this way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

<liferay-util:include page="/html/book.jsp" useCustomPage="false" servletContext="<%= application %>"/>
```

(First I thought that useCustomPage="false" solves the issue, but not,
when I tested it turned out, that file cache was the reason, so you do not have to use useCustomPage="false")

Beware, that portal must be restarted, because it caches the files, and if it was not found for some reason in the past, it will not search again after it on the file system and will not include it and redeploy does not empty the cache.

I use 6.2 CA G5.

Comment: hi Peter B . excuse me for later answer. it works for one jsp page and doesnt work for other. and i do copy that page  for all pages in the project and replace with them.

Comment: So you can find a workaround for your problem. The question is interesting, though. Maybe, you can write your answer if you suspect what causes this peculiar phenomenon.